# How do I play this chord with an overlapping sharp and flat?

Tags: chords, accidentals

[image: Measure 39 from Louis Moreau Gottschalk's "Manchega"]

How do I play this chord (underneath the red arrow in the attached image) that seems to have both D sharp and an E flat? Am I misreading it?

EDIT: the clip is from the piece "Manchega" by Louis Moreau Gottschalk. Here's a link to the sheet music I'm using: https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ReverseLookup/3054

Comment: Does indeed look like a D#, with Eb above. So seems like 'play the same black key', which can't be right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a mistake. It should be E# instead of D#. It's clearly audible in the recording:

Possible reason for the mistake is that D# is much more commonly used than E#. However it's a very reasonable use. The section is in the key of Gb. The first half of the measure is Gb chord, while the second half is D chord. F# is a chord tone for D, while E# is #9, a common alteration; or perhaps it's a chromatic ornamentation of F#.  Writing F instead of E# would not only require using more accidentals in the measure, but also wouldn't make harmonic sense.

Answer (score 18):

As [@user1079505 points out](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/116367/70803), recorded versions of the piece include an E#. This begs the question, though: **how do they know to play E#**?

One way would be a more modern edition that contains the correction. But that still begs the question of how the editor(s) knew.

## How does an editor or performer know that `E#` is correct?

#### The holograph manuscript

Gottschalk's original, handwritten manuscript is held by the New York Public Library ([WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/manchega-autograph/oclc/24086849)). In principle, a researcher could consult the original to see if Gottschalk wrote an `E#`, with the error being introduced in the process of publishing the first edition. Unfortunately, the NYPL only has the first page of the manuscript, which does not contain measure 39.<sup>1</sup>

#### The musical evidence

However, even without access to the holograph, examining the published edition (presuming the remainder is correct) gives clues supporting `E#`.

The B section's defining musical gesture is `Db-Eb-F Gb-F-Gb`:

```
X: 1
T: Manchega
T: B section motif
C: Louis Moreau Gottschalk
K: Gb
D'E'F' {/A'}G'F'/2G'/2 z
```

This gesture occurs four times, in measures 33, 35, 37, and 39.

Measures 33, 35, and 37 all contain exactly these same pitches. In measure 39, beat 4 is re-notated from `Gb` to `F#`, because the underlying harmony is `D major`. (This serves as a pivot chord. It's the `vi` chord borrowed from `Gb minor` [i.e., Ebb major] and also the `iv` chord of `A major` [i.e., D major], where the music arrives on measure 40, beats 5 and 6.)

Given the melodic consistency and harmonic context, there is no reason the `F#` would be decorated with `Eb`, which is musically jarring at least, if not altogether nonsensical. `E#` maintains (enharmonic) consistency with the preceding three occurrences, which contain `F`.

Further, the `D#` in the same chord makes little sense for the same reason (consistency with the other occurrences of the gesture) as well as the presence of `D` in the left hand.

**Even more reliably than the autograph, this makes clear Gottschalk's intention that the `Eb` should be `E#` (and the `D#` should be `D`).**

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>That only the first page is in the collection (call #: JPB 84-13 no. 31 [Score]) was confirmed in email communication with the library on 22 Sept 2021. The only other edition held by the NYPL is the William Hall & Son edition, which does contain the error. That edition is [available on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Manchega%2C_Op.38_(Gottschalk%2C_Louis_Moreau)).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a misprint to me.  I suspect the sharp is intended for the E.